# remove special character from string in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

this would be my string

**Panipat,Patna,**

Result should be **Panipat,Patna**

**,Panipat,Patna,**

Result should be **Panipat,Patna**

**Panipat,**

Result should be **Panipat**

**,Panipat,,**

Result should be **Panipat**

How can i do it . Need help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want the `Trim` function

```
Dim result = input.Trim(New Char() { ","c })
```

This function will remove all occurrences of the specified characters from the start and end of the string value

Example usage

```
Dim str As String = "hello,"
Dim res = str.Trim(New Char() {","c})
Console.WriteLine(res) 'Prints: hello
```

Comment: @coders_zone did you make sure to assign the result back?  This will work if you put the right character into the `Char` array.  I editted my answer to have a complete working example

Comment: @coders_zone the `c` is used to make the string be treated as a `Char`.  Example: `"h"` is a `String` while `"h"c` is a `Char`

Comment: it's done. I've used `str.Trim()` before `Dim res = str.Trim(New Char() {","c})` and now, it works !!

Answer (score 0):

You can get more info from [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace-vbnet)

```
Function RemoveCharacter(ByVal stringToCleanUp, ByVal characterToRemove)
   Return stringToCleanUp.Replace(characterToRemove, "")
End Function
```

Try with this:

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim inputText As String = "This is string ending with comma character,"

    Dim result As String = inputText.Trim(",".ToCharArray())

    Console.WriteLine(result)

End Sub
```

Comment: That will also replace the commas in the middle of the string

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve your goal is use regular expression. Below example will work for two terms at a time.

e.g replace ,Panipat,Patna,, with Panipat,Patna

```
Public Function Return_Strip_Word(Text As String) As String
    Dim reg As String = "(?<stripword>(\w+)\b,\b(\w+))"
    Dim VDMatch As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Text, reg)
    If VDMatch.Success Then
         Return VDMatch.Groups("stripword").Value
    Else
        Return Text
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Regular expressions are overkill for this simple task. The `Trim`, `TrimStart`, and `TrimEnd` methods were made for this.

Comment: in some cases you not know which special character will be in start or end of string. if you already know then trim is preferred option.